# maven-shade like plugin for SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, maven-shade-plugin

i'm rellatively new to the scala and sbt world and i'm trying to manage all my new projects with sbt rather than using maven. But now i'm on a point where I dont know further because I can't find any sbt counterpart for the mavnen-shade plugin. What I found only were plugins to include all dependencies, but that is not what I need. So do somebody know a plugin to include certain dependencies into the jar ?

Comment: I've been writing Scala since 2.7 and I still prefer to use Maven, FWIW.

Comment: Does the [sbt-assembly plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) do what you want?

Comment: Not exactly, it renames all files in jar like "OrginalClassName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.class" so the classloader does not find them.

Comment: If your asking what I think your asking, I cannot believe this has only 1 upvote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

sbt-assembly 0.14.0 adds [shading](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading) support.

> sbt-assembly can shade classes from your projects or from the library dependencies. Backed by Jar Jar Links, bytecode transformation (via ASM) is used to change references to the renamed classes.

```scala
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("org.apache.commons.io.**" -> "shadeio.@1").inAll
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with Proguard using the [sbt-proguard](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-proguard) plugin.  It took me a while to get it set up, and I had to turn off some of the Proguard features to get it working, but in the end I got what I wanted: a single jar I could execute with "java -jar", even on a system without scala installed.

Here is my `project/plugins.sbt` to enable the plugin:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases-scalasbt", url("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-proguard" % "0.2.2")
```

And here are some snippets from my build.sbt to configure it:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

proguardSettings

ProguardKeys.options in Proguard += ProguardOptions.keepMain("io.package.my.app.Main")

ProguardKeys.options in Proguard ++= Seq(
  "-keep class com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.XWSSProcessorFactory2_0Impl { *; }", // created dynamically by XWSSProcessorFactory
  //
  "-dontshrink",
  "-dontobfuscate",
  "-dontoptimize",
  //
  // Don't warn is necessary to avoid ProGuard refusing to build the jar.
  //
  "-dontwarn com.sun.**",
  "-dontwarn org.apache.**",
  "-dontwarn scala.**",
  //
  // Don't note just reduces clutter in the build output.  If you make changes
  // to the ProGuard configuration, you might want to remove these temporarily to
  // help debug the new configuration until it's working correctly.
  //
  "-dontnote com.sun.**",
  "-dontnote org.apache.**",
  "-dontnote scala.**"
)

  //"-printconfiguration /tmp/proguard"

// Examples of how to filter classes.
ProguardKeys.inputFilter in Proguard := { file =>
  file.name match {
    case "classes"                                  => None
    case "org.apache.karaf.shell.console-2.3.2.jar" => Some("org/apache/karaf/shell/**,org/apache/felix/gogo/commands/**")
    case "jline-2.9.jar"                            => Some("jline/**")
    case "org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules-2.3.2.jar"  => Some("org/apache/karaf/jaas/modules/**")
    case "org.apache.karaf.jaas.config-2.3.2.jar"   => Some("org/apache/karaf/jaas/config/**")
    case "org.osgi.compendium-4.3.1.jar"            => Some("!**")
    case _                                          => Some("!META-INF/**")
  }
}
```